# Reading Mysql DB Files Manually

Tags: c++, mysql, file

I wonder if there is a way I can read mysql database files (*.MYI, *.MYD, *.frm) manually using something like a filestream? 
I can read these files but the content does not make sense, I don't know the content structure in here.

Regards

Comment: Read [MYSQL Internals MyISAM](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/MySQL_Internals_MyISAM). It's a good overview of MyISAM's records structure and table's indexes structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Yes you can but it is not very clever to reinvent wheel...

See for example http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/MySQL_Internals_MyISAM

Comment: Thank you, I don't want to reinvent the wheel, I'm trying to get familiar with the fundamentals of current wheel :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/MySQL_Internals_File_Formats) to create a parser that will help you read the file.s

Comment: Sorry but contents of the link in first answer was more related to my question. I appreciate your help.

Comment: The comment was to remind you should accept any of the answers, not exactly mine. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is one more way to work with "raw" MyISAM tables: using "[Embedded MySQL Server Library](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/libmysqld.html)". Why? Because MySQL has an embedded server library, **libmysqld**, that contains the server in a form that can be linked (embedded) into applications.

BTW, there is a [quite similar question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/9900) on dba.stackexchange.com. You should read it.